# Wordpress add_menu_page() - no content displayed

Tags: wordpress

I'm using add_menu_page() to add a new menu to manage my plugin.

But no matter what I try, no content is displayed when I click the button on the menu. Here's the code:

```
class Personalize_Login_Plugin {

    public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'my_admin_menu' ));
    }
    public function my_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page( 'Project Management', 'Project Management', 'manage_options', 'testing_page', 'my_admin_page', 'dashicons-star-filled', 6);
    }

    public function my_admin_page(){

        ?>
        <h3>Testing options</h3>
        <div>put more stuf here</div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, consider to use

```
 public function my_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page( 'Project Management', 'Project Management', 'manage_options', 'testing_page', array( $this, 'my_admin_page' ), 'dashicons-star-filled', 6);
    }
```

Comment: The quickest, most concise answer I've had on SO. Thank you Sir, that works.